# Get value of field in nested object with jQuery or Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have the following JS object:

```
{
   "gameName":"Shooter",
   "details":[
      {
         "submitted":1415215991387,
         "author":"XYZ",
         "subPlayer":{
            "members":{
               "squad1":[
                  {
                     "username":"John",
                     "deaths":0
                  }
               ]
            },
            "gameSlug":"0-shooter"
         }
      }
   ],
   "userId":"foL9NpoZFq9AYmXyj",
   "author":"Peter",
   "submitted":1415215991608,
   "lastModified":1415215991608,
   "participants":[
      "CXRR4sGf5AdvSjdgc",
      "foL9NpoZFq9AYmXyj"
   ],
   "slug":"1-shooterConv",
   "_id":"p2QQ4TBwidjeZX6YS"
}
```

And I want to get the deaths for the correct user.

My current code is something like this:

```
$.map(this.details.subPlayer.members.squad1, function(obj) {
            if(obj.username == Meteor.user().username) {
                return obj.deaths;
            }
        });
```

However, the problem is that I don't know exactly the squad name (e.g. `squad1`). How can I get `deaths` for the corresponding username in any squad?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Get the object `this.details[0].subPlayer.members` and loop over its keys. Then for that key, you can access the `deaths`: `this.details[0].subPlayer.members[foundKey].deaths`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using underscore, You can use: `data.details[0].subPlayer.members`

```
var data = {
   "gameName":"Shooter",
   "details":[
      {
         "submitted":1415215991387,
         "author":"XYZ",
         "subPlayer":{
            "members":{
               "squad1":[
                  {
                     "username":"John",
                     "deaths":0
                  }
               ]
            },
            "gameSlug":"0-shooter"
         }
      }
   ],
   "userId":"foL9NpoZFq9AYmXyj",
   "author":"Peter",
   "submitted":1415215991608,
   "lastModified":1415215991608,
   "participants":[
      "CXRR4sGf5AdvSjdgc",
      "foL9NpoZFq9AYmXyj"
   ],
   "slug":"1-shooterConv",
   "_id":"p2QQ4TBwidjeZX6YS"
}
```

```js
function getDeaths(data) {
    var members = data.details[0].subPlayer.members;
    return _.map(members, function(key, value){
        return {
            member: value,
            deaths: members[value][0].deaths
        }
    });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getDeaths(data), null, '  '));
```

This returns:

```
[
  {
    "member": "squad1",
    "deaths": 0
  }
]
```

You can filter the results by squad and username. The squadname is optional, but the username must match.

```
function getDeaths(data, username, squad) {
    var users = [];
    var members = data.details[0].subPlayer.members;
    _.each(members, function(squads, squadName) {
        if (!squad || (squad && squadName === squad)) {
            _.each(squads, function(user, index) {
                if (user.username === username) {
                    users.push(user);
                }
            })
        }
    });
    return users;
}
var deaths = getDeaths(data, 'John', 'squad1');
console.log(JSON.stringify(deaths, null, '  '));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but how can I return only the `deaths` where `username == Meteor.user().username`?